# PowerShell UICulture vs. Windows setting

Tags: powershell, windows-10, currentuiculture, uiculture

During my tinkering with PS 5.1 under Win 10, related to the objective of question [Fully change language (including Culture) for the current PowerShell session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62872708/fully-change-language-for-the-current-powershell-session),
I came across a couple of related questions.

1. Where is the Windows setting associated with the UICulture?
   I did not find the "*Keyboard and Languages*" tab of the "*Region and Language*" control panel as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17053067/2707864).
2. Can this be persistently changed from within PS?
   All I found so far only persist in a session.

---

The setting *Settings* -> *Time and Language* -> *Language* -> *Windows display language* shows "Español (España)", and PS gives

```
> Get-UICulture ; [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture ; [CultureInfo]::CurrentUICulture ;
LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             -----------
1033             en-US            English (United States)
1033             en-US            English (United States)
1033             en-US            English (United States)
```

without any intervening changes and in a session just launched.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In **.NET**, ***cultures* ([`System.Globalization.CultureInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo))** are used to control **two related, but independent aspects of (human) culture-specific *for-display representations***:

- The **effective *UI culture***, reflected in [`[cultureinfo]::CurrentUICulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture), controls the **(human) language** that should be used for **UI elements and end-user messages**, such as error messages.

  - On Windows, its value is inherited from the so-called **Windows *display language***, which is a **persistent, user-specific setting** that you can modify as described below.
  - In PowerShell, you can also query the effective UI culture via the automatic [`$PSUICulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psuiculture) variable  (reports the culture *name* only) or the [`Get-UICulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-UICulture) cmdlet (reports a `[cultureinfo]` instance).
    **Caveat**: In *Windows PowerShell*, the value reported is the one that was in effect at *session start-up time* (which was the then-current persisted value), so any in-session changes are *not* reflected. This problem has been corrected in PowerShell [Core] v6+.
- The **effective *culture***, reflected in [`[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), controls the **formats used to represent numbers, currency values, and date/time values**.

  - On Windows, its value is inherited from the active ***locale***, a.k.a. **regional format**, which are **persistent, user-specific setting**s that you can modify as described below.
  - In PowerShell, you can also query the effective UI culture via the automatic [`$PSCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psculture) variable (reports the culture *name* only) [`Get-Culture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-Culture) cmdlet (reports a `[cultureinfo]` instance).
    **Caveat**: In *Windows PowerShell*, the value reported is the one that was in effect at *session start-up time*, so any in-session changes are *not* reflected. This problem has been corrected in PowerShell [Core] v6+.

---

### Switching to a different culture:

#### *Interactive* (GUI) methods, which are invariably *persistent*, for the *current user*:

- **UI culture, a.k.a Windows display language**:

  - On Windows 10, open the **Settings application** (e.g., via Start Menu), go to category `Time & Language`, then click on `Language` in the sidebar on the left.

    - Shortcuts:

      - Open the Settings app quickly:

        - Use keyboard shortcut <kbd>WinKey-i</kbd>.
        - Run `start ms-settings:` (works from `cmd` too).
      - In Start Menu, simply type "Language" and select `Language Settings` from the result - this takes you directly to the relevant page in the Settings app.
      - Run `intl.cpl` to open the legacy `Region` Control Panel applet and click on the `Language preferences` link, which takes you to the relevant page in the Settings app.
- **Culture, a.k.a Regional format (locale)**:

  - On Windows 10, open the **Settings application** (e.g., via Start Menu), go to category `Time & Language`, then click on `Region` in the sidebar on the left, then select the desired culture under `Regional format` (the `Region` setting at the top does *not* control the culture).

    - Shortcuts:

      - In Start Menu, simply type "Regional format" and select `Set regional format` from the result - this takes you directly to the relevant page in the Settings app.
      - Run `intl.cpl` to open the legacy `Region` Control Panel applet and select the desired culture from the `Format:` drop-down list.

**Note**:
These **settings apply to .NET and non-.NET applications equally**, assuming these applications are designed to respect the user's regional formats (locale, culture) and display language (UI culture) and come with language-specific resources.
By contrast, making in-session-only changes via `[cultureinfo]::CurrentUICulture` / `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture` (see below) applies to .NET applications only.

#### *Programmatic* methods:

- ***Persistent, current-user* changes (equivalents of the GUI methods)**:

  - **UI culture, a.k.a Windows display language**:

    - There is *no* <del>`Set-UICulture`</del> cmdlet, but in Windows 8 / Windows Server 2012 R2 and above you can use the
      [`Set-WinUILanguageOverride`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-winuilanguageoverride) cmdlet.
      Note that the language pack for the language associated with the targeted culture must either come with the system or must have been downloaded previously.
    - **Important**: The change doesn't take effect until you either **log off and back on or reboot**.
  - **Culture, a.k.a Regional format (locale)**:

    - Use the [`Set-Culture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-culture) cmdlet, available in Windows 8 / Windows Server 2012 R2 and above.
    - **Important**: The change only takes effect in ***future* PowerShell sessions**, but no logoff / reboot is required.
- ***In-session-only* changes**:

  - **Important**: Such changes are **apply only to *.NET-based* applications**. Therefore, calling a non-.NET console application from a PowerShell session in which culture was changed will have no impact on that console application. However, **the change *does* take effect for calls to PowerShell cmdlets, scripts and functions**. Even though the scope of the change is technically limited to the *current thread*, PowerShell also propagates the change to code executed in *new* threads (`Start-ThreadJob` and `ForEach-Object -Parallel`) as well as code executed on *remote machines*, via PowerShell remoting (e.g., `Invoke-Command`). Curiously, however, **as of PowerShell 7.0, *background jobs* (`Start-Job`), which run in child processes, do *not* inherit the calling thread's culture** - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13289).
  - You can *assign* to `[cultureinfo]::CurrentUICulture` / `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture` to change the UI culture / culture for the *current thread* (only, non-persistently); e.g., the following command outputs the current date and time using the French culture:

    - `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture = 'fr-FR'; Get-Date`
  - **Caveat**: Due to a *bug in Windows PowerShell*, `[cultureinfo]::CurrentUICulture` and `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture` are  unexpectedly *reset to the session start-up values* after every interactively submitted command; this problem has been fixed in PowerShell [Core] v6+ - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56922526/45375).
  - The upshot is that **if you want to run entire PowerShell sessions with different cultures than persistently configured**, you can  **place assignments to `[cultureinfo]::CurrentUICulture` and `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture` in your `$PROFILE` file in PowerShell [Core] v6+**, but you'll need a ***workaround* for *Windows PowerShell*** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118816/2707864).

    - **Caveat**: Windows PowerShell *statically* initializes **`$PSUICulture` and `$PSCulture`** and therefore these variables **do *not* reflect the effective culture set by the workaround** (which relies on modifying a *non-public* field); however, `Get-UICulture` / `Get-Culture` as well as `[cultureinfo]::CurrentUICulture` / `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture` do.

Answer (score 0):

This answer complements [that by mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62940162/2707864).
The setting in a PS session is inherited from *Win Settings* -> *Time and Language* -> *Language* -> *Display language for Windows* upon starting the session.

So to change this "persistently" for all sessions one has to change the Windows setting.
Alternatively, one can [change this only for the PS session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118816/2707864) in `profile.ps1`, and this would not "taint" the Windows configuration.

I am not certain any of this can be managed by directly accessing `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International` ([[ref](https://dennisspan.com/configuring-regional-settings-and-windows-locales-with-group-policy/)]) (or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment`?) from PS.

Note that (in Windows PowerShell) `$PSUICulture` is statically initialized at the time of the last Windows logon by retrieving the Windows setting above.
So it is insensitive to the current PS setting (possibly changed during the current PS session).
So `$PSUICulture` may differ from `Get-UICulture`.
This would not apply to PowerShell Core.

Comment: Good points; I've restructured my answer to incorporate most of them. I wouldn't recommend dealing with the registry directly, because changing the culture changes a whole raft of registry values. As for what `$PSUICulture` / `$PSCulture` / `Get-UICulture` / `Get-Culture` reflect: in PowerShell [Core] v6+, they - sensibly  - reflect the values currently in effect. In Windows PowerShell, unfortunately, they always reflect the values at session start-up time.

Comment: I've added a paragraph about the scope of in-session culture changes to my answer, which includes discovery of a surprising inconsistency. It is implied by my previous comment, but to spell it out: The statement "So $PSUICulture may differ from Get-UICulture." is not correct: for a given edition, the results are always the same (except for the data type), but the editions differ by what value they report (current value in PSCore, session-start-up value in WinPS). Can you please either correct this, or, given that my answer now hopefully tells the full story, consider deleting your answer?

Comment: @mklement0 - This is what I see. 
`> $PSUICulture ; Get-UICulture
<br>
es-ES
<br>
LCID             Name             DisplayName
<br>
----             ----             -----------
<br>
1033             en-US            English (United States)
<br>
`
Why do you say my statement is not correct? Perhaps I should rephrase "The screen output of `$PSUICulture` may differ from `Get-UICulture`"?

Comment: 1) `> $PSUICulture ; (Get-UICulture).Name 
<br>
es-ES
<br>
en-US
`
Preceding this with `[cultureinfo]::CurrentUICulture = <culture> ; ` does not change output with either `'en-US'`, `'es-ES'`, `'es-AR'`, 
2) Script `Set-PowerShellUICulture` loaded in `profile.ps1`,
3) PS 5.1.17763.1007

Comment: I see - that is _solely_ because of the _hack_ that `Set-PowerShellUICulture` constitutes (modification of a _non-public_ field), so you should make that clear (you wouldn't face that problem in PowerShell [Core] v6+, where assigning to `[cultureinfo]::CurrentUICulture` in `$PROFILE` is sufficient). The reason for the discrepancy with the hack is that WinPS _statically_ initializes `$PSUICulture` / `$PSCulture`, so it is unaware of the change performed by the hack. I've added a warning to my answer, and I've also left a(nother) comment at the answer that contains the hack.

Comment: Ok. Would you think there is any implication in WinPS, other than the fact that the value of `$PSUICulture` may not be meaningful for the current session?

Comment: It is the only ramification I am personally aware of, and I _think_ it's the only one, but I'm not sure - that's the problem with using such a hack (as helpful as it is in principle).